# Search and replace with backreference with modification

Tags: regex, vim, replace

Question for vim power users:

`file1.txt`

````
Some list
 - line 1
 - line 2

Example of payload:

```json
{
    "order_id": "ABC123",
    "postcode": "A1 B22",
    "items": [1, 2, 3]
}
```

More text follows.
````

My goal is to:

- match everything that is in between  ```` ```json ```` and ```` ``` ````
- get rid of those prefix/suffix
- and prepend each line with extra spaces (add indentation). The result would be something like that:

`file2.txt`

```
Some list
 - line 1
 - line 2

Example of payload:

    {
        "order_id": "ABC123",
        "postcode": "A1 B22",
        "items": [1, 2, 3]
    }

More text follows.
```

So far I managed to non-greedy match everything between json and backticks via:

````
%s/```json\(\_.\{-}\)```/\1/g
````

But prepending each line of `\1` is an entirely different story.

Things I experimented with is:

- submatch (i.e. ```` %s/```json\(\_.\{-}\)```/\=submatch(1)/g ````)
- trying to chain replaces (but I have no idea how to do it)

Any help/suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it in two steps:

````
:g/```json/.,/```/s/^/    /
:g/```/d
````

The first step:

- `:g/<pattern>/<command>` executes `<command>` on each line matching `<pattern>`.
- ```` ```json ```` is our `<pattern>`, the rest is our `<command>`, a simple substitution.
- ```` .,/```/ ```` is a range that covers every line from the current line, `.`, to the line of the next ```` ``` ````.
- `s/^/    /` essentially prepends the line with 4 spaces.

This effectively indents the whole fenced block:

````
    ```json
    {
        "order_id": "ABC123",
        "postcode": "A1 B22",
        "items": [1, 2, 3]
    }
    ```
````

The second step:

- `:g/<pattern>/<command>` executes `<command>` on each line matching `<pattern>`, like above.
- ```` ``` ```` is our `<pattern>`.
- `d` is our `<command>`.

This effectively removes the extraneous fences:

```
    {
        "order_id": "ABC123",
        "postcode": "A1 B22",
        "items": [1, 2, 3]
    }
```

See `:help :global`.

Comment: That indeed helped me to solve my issue, I could not use the later command as I had lines with ``` all over the place, but using the first command to tab everything and my regex to trim prefix/suffix did the trick. Thank you very much!